# How to create coordinates for a grid in Haskell

Tags: haskell, grid

Im attempting to define a function `grid :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]` that returns a list of all (x, y) coordinate pairs on an n × n square grid.

```hs
    grid :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
    grid x y = [x y| |(x <- [1..x] y <- [1..y])]
```

GHCi tells me

```
    parse error on input ‘<-’
    Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
 grid n = [(x, y)| x<- [0..n], y<-[0..n]]
```

Comment: yeah I am having problems with the correct syntax. So that fixes one part. But also how can i define N which is the size of the grid?

Comment: xMax and yMax are the width and height of the rectangle....  This will return all x,y integer points in that rectangle.

Comment: will this work `grid x y n = [(x, y)| x<- [0..n], y<-[0..n]]`

Comment: you don't need the x and y on the left side of the definition....  Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Just add a condition `[(x, y)| x <- [0..n], y<-[0..n], x /= y]`.

Comment: lol i didn't see your comment took me time to work this out. But thanks

Comment: @ProtectorOfUbi, you can highlight the independence of `x` and `y` by using `grid n = (,) <$> [0..n] <*> [0..n]` instead.